# R - extract t-values from a list of multiple lms

Tags: r

I have a dataframe a vector with a dependent variable. For example like this:

```
a <- rnorm(100,1,1)
b <- rnorm(100,2,2)
c <- rnorm(100,3,3)
x <- rbind(a,b,c)

y <- rnorm(100,5,10)
```

Now I need to run a linear regression for every row. I did it like this:

```
lm.list <- apply(x,1, function(x) lm(x ~ y))
```

I managed to extract the coefficients by adding "$coefficients" like this:

```
lm.list <- apply(x,1, function(x) lm(x ~ y)$coefficients)
```

I then get the coefficients for each row. Now I would like to know the significance of those coefficients. So I need to extract either the t-values, the standard errors or the p-values. I dont know how to do it and i dont want to run the lm-function for each row 1 by 1 and copy paste the t-values. Is there a way to do this?

And as a bonus question: is it possible to use Newey-West standard errors for the coeffient calculation for each row? I know how it works for single lms but could not find a way to use it with the apply function for many rows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those kinds of manipulations, it is easier to work with lists and thus `lapply` family.
First note: your a,b,c are variables, not records -> this is  a strange idea to rbind them instead of cbind or in fact creating a dataset to hold them, as in:

```
data=data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Note that a data.frame is a list -> we can invoke lapply:

```
lm.list=lapply(data,FUN=function(x) lm(x~y))
```

(by the way, usually one has y~x and not the reverse)

So what do we have so far? A list with each component holding an object of class `lm` -- basically a list of components, look for instance at :

```
> names(lm.list[["a"]])
 [1] "coefficients"  "residuals"     "effects"       "rank"          "fitted.values" "assign"        "qr"            "df.residual"  
 [9] "xlevels"       "call"          "terms"         "model"
```

You can extract values out of this:

```
> (coeffs=sapply(lm.list, FUN=function(item){item$coefficients}))
                  a           b           c
```

(Intercept)  1.36869810 1.759809965  3.16491826
    y           -0.01885792 0.002648734 -0.02690408

If you wanted to have t-values and associated on a `lm` object, you would call `summary` on it. Let's do this on whole list with `lapply`:

```
lm.list.summary = lapply(lm.list,summary)
```

Don't forget `str` function to check object structure/content:

```
str(lm.list.summary[[1]])
```

Then it is just a matter of correcly setting a path to what you want to extract, such as:

```
y.tval = sapply(lm.list.summary, FUN=function(item){item$coefficients["y","t value"]})
y.tval
         a          b          c 
-1.7599765  0.1366731 -0.7998487
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the good explanations! Thats what i wanted! Thank you!